# How to unit test Scheduler using NUnit

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, nunit

How to unit test a scheduler using NUnit which can allow scheduling capability similar to the Outlook schedule?

The scheduler is programmed to send the messages daily/weekly/monthly/yearly at a specific time or a specific day of week/month.

If I use hard coded dates then after sometime test cases will fail. Also how to test the monthly and yearly schedule?

-

Ram

Comment: Provide interface of a scheduler you've mentioned otherwise question does not make any sense and will be closed soon

Answer (score 1):

Abstract the date and time checking of the scheduler into a separate interface. Have a class which implements this interface for your live code / environment (Using DateTime or whatever is currently used) and one which implements it for your testing enviroment which allows you to accelerate / change time. That way you can test time based functionality quickly and on the fly.

A **very** simple example, this will vary depending on your scheduler:

```
public interface IDateTimeProvider
{
    DateTime CurrentDateTime { get; }
}

public class DateTimeProvider : IDateTimeProvider
{
    public DateTime CurrentDateTime
    {
        get { return DateTime.Now; }
    }
}

public class TestDateTimeProvider : IDateTimeProvider
{
    public DateTime CurrentDateTime { get; set; }
}

public class Scheduler
{
    private readonly IDateTimeProvider DateTimeProvider;

    public Scheduler(IDateTimeProvider provider)
    {
        DateTimeProvider = provider;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

At some point in time you're Scheduler will check the current date and will check it against the scheduled items.

If you make sure that the 'Check the current date' part is separated in another component you can switch this behavior in your unit tests and let it return a specified date.

public interface IDateTimeManager
        {
            DateTime GetCurrentDateTime();
        }

```
    class ProductionDateTimeManager : IDateTimeManager
    {
        public DateTime GetCurrentDateTime()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public class Scheduler
    {
        public Scheduler(IDateTimeManager dateTimeManager)
        {
            this.DateTimeManager = dateTimeManager;
        }

        public Scheduler()
        {
            this.DateTimeManager = new ProductionDateTimeManager();
        }

        public void Execute()
        {
            DateTime current = DateTimeManager.GetCurrentDateTime();
        }

        private IDateTimeManager DateTimeManager { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use tools like Moles to deal with DateTime.Now
http://angler.wordpress.com/2010/01/21/pex-and-moles-untestable-code-not-really/